# What are the REST calls to import a CSV file into Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

We saw https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api but couldn't find a detailed documentation of the APIs.

EDIT: I found https://my-shop-host.example/api/v2/_info/swagger.html which describes all available APIs and `import-export-file` endpoints, but it is not clearly described how to use them (and which ones to use).

I believe we need to call (extracted from the admin panel work flow)

- /api/v2/_action/import-export/prepare

and then

- /api/v2/_action/import-export/process

to trigger an import.

But how are the files uploaded?

Is there an easier way, for example in one call?

Comment: Just import the file via UI and have a look at the network tab of your browser, the Admin is an api client too. So I think there is not better example as the calls the admin does.

Comment: I did and I copied the curl commands from the network tab but did not see the files getting transferred. Also I am wondering why the prepare and process calls are not in the swagger docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start with the authentication

```
curl 'http://example.com/api/oauth/token'\
  -H 'Accept: pplication/vnd.api+json'\
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "<my client ID from the integration>",
    "client_secret": "<my secret>"
  }'  | jq .access_token
```

This returns and auth token which is valid for 10 minutes.

I store it to the variable `$B`

Next I upload the file and set the expiry date to 10 days in the future:

```
curl 'http://example.com/api/v2/_action/import-export/prepare' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $B"
  --form "file=@\"products.csv\"" --form "profileId=d4ec3999a33242a690ca5c213a7145cd" --form "expireDate=+10 days"    | jq .log.id
```

This returns a log.id field

This field must be passed to the process call

```
curl 'http://example.com/api/v2/_action/import-export/process'  \
 -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' \ 
 -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $B"  --data '{"logId":"1410eaa1ca434744a8c211b60f65a3c5","offset":0}'
```

EDIT: Each chunk has to be triggered separately by using the last returned offset and pass it again to the `process` call.