# How to import products to Shopware via Python

Tags: python, shopware

I have following data of the products:
SKU, Name, Price, Reduced Price, Description, manufacturer, EAN, images

is this enough and how do i import the product via api to shopware 6 (in python)?

thank you so much for any help

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is about Shopware 6.

As Shopware 6 is fully API driven, everything you can do with the Admin Panel can be done via API.

If you have many products to import you might want to use the CSV import via API:

[What are the REST calls to import a CSV file into Shopware 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336872/what-are-the-rest-calls-to-import-a-csv-file-into-shopware-6)

Or you can write the entities via directly API calls, see here for details: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTQ5-introduction

Comment: yes i read all but how to do that in python? like how to do the api calls in python, i assume they all use c or something like this