# Synchronizing millions of products

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

My team and I are trying update a huge number (millions) of products through integration with ERP.
We want to use the sync api.

https://forum.shopware.com/t/sync-api-upsert-mit-productnumber-als-unique-key/68556
Explains what we want to do. Our ERP system is not aware of the product id (UUID) from shopware and only knows a product SKU. This leaves us with having to do a product lookup in shopware for each product number, to get product id and then update the product data.

Is there a workaround so we can upsert by product number or other great ideas on how we can speed up things?

Kind regards

One idea is to generate our own product UUID based on MD5 hash of the product number. This way we will always know the uuid without having to do lookup in database.

Comment: We do have similar issues. Currently we plan to write an own API endpoint with SKU as primary. Sadly we haven't found any alternative in any other API endpoint (sync/product). At the moment though we still use a middleware to build the request for the sync API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches to solve this. This are some which i use in my daily business.

**API-only**

If you do can only work with the sync-API, then i would recommend to build a sep. storage only for product synchronization. This would contain the following information:

1. SKU
2. Shopware-UUID
3. hash

Every synchronized product will have an existing UUID. If there is no UUID, you know that the product has not been synchronized to Shopware. The hash itself can be used internally to check for changes in the data. If there is a change, that specific entity will be updated then. In that way a simple and fast lookup would be possible without the API.

**Direct access to the db**

This is not my recommendation if you do not have a team of developers. Direct access to the database will provide you the fastest ways to access that information. Actually we do this for merchants with lots of product data but you will loose some benefits like the automatically queued events for updating entities in the catalog, prices, categories, etc. when using the sync api. So i only recommend it for read access which is what you want.

**About the UUID**

The approach you described is exactly what UUID v5 is. Shopware uses UUID v4 internally, which is just a random 128 bit sequence while v5 utilizes sha1 to generate that. So this is a good practice.

Comment: We will be generating the ID's based off md5 has key. Thanks a lot for your recommendations!

Answer (score 2):

Shopwares API only allows updated by the primary key/id, so updates by other (unique) are not supported. Neither in the the sync api, nor in the default crud api.

But providing IDs for the products yourself instead of letting shopware auto generate them is totally valid, so your idea of generating the id based on the product number sounds reasonable and feasible to me.

Another solution would be to store the mapping between the shopware ids and the SKUs somewhere where you can access it faster, this would probably mean storing the ids either directly in the ERP (in some form of custom field etc.) or store that information in the mapping service. But i would prefer having a fast and consistent way of regenerating the ids without the need to store the mapping.

Comment: Also really good thoughts. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Shopware CSV import which allows mapping using the product number since a while. [The CSV import also can be driven by API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336872/what-are-the-rest-calls-to-import-a-csv-file-into-shopware-6)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - We are connecting to an API Gateway from ERP system and would like to avoid file transfers.

Comment: I can understand if you want to avoid CSVs :-) Just for clarification: That is not a SFTP or similar file transfer - the CSV would still be uploaded via API.